# How to import perforce .patch in to perforce new Changlist

Tags: perforce

I have perforce .patch file generated, wanted to import that file in current ChangeList.
was exploring options but did not find command for.

Comment: How exactly did you generate this file?  There's no such thing as a "perforce .patch file" that I'm aware of.

Comment: Googling tells me that P4Eclipse has its own notion of patch files, which you need to apply using P4Eclipse: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4eclipse/Content/P4Eclipse/patch.html.  The standard Perforce tool for moving pending changes around is *shelving*, but that doesn't create a local .patch file.